# ERROR [22P02]: invalid input syntax for integer: “”

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I have a issue with the query presented below:

```
select p."Index", p."PSN" || cast(p."PNR"as int) as ID
, p."PSN" as Serie, cast(p."PNR"as int) as Numar
, pr."PINDate" as r_gdate
, replace((CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN pr."PrimSUM" ELSE 
    pr."PrimSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue" END)::text, '.', ',') as r_prima_lei
, replace(CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='2' 
        THEN cast(pr."PrimSUM" as decimal(12,2))
      ELSE CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN cast(pr."PrimSUM"/valuta2."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2))
           ELSE cast(pr."PrimSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue"/valuta2."EXCValue" as decimal(12,2))
           END 
    END::text, '.', ',') as r_prima_eur
, replace((CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN cast(pr."AsigSUM" as decimal(12,2)) ELSE 
    cast(pr."AsigSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2)) END)::text, '.', ',') as r_sa_lei
, replace(CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='2' 
        THEN cast(pr."AsigSUM" as decimal(12,2))
      ELSE CASE WHEN pr."AsigEID"='10' THEN cast(pr."AsigSUM"/valuta2."EXCValue"  as decimal(12,2))
           ELSE cast(pr."AsigSUM"*valuta1."EXCValue"/valuta2."EXCValue" as decimal(12,2))
           END 
    END::text, '.', ',') as r_sa_eur
, pr."AsigStart", pr."AsigEnd", risc."Code", plink."Index"
from "PolsRisc" as pr 
left join "Pols" as p on p."Index" = pr."PID"
left join "Riscs" as risc on pr."RID"=risc."Index"
left join "PRLNK" plink on plink."PTID"= p."PTID" and plink."RID"= risc."Index"
LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" valuta1 ON valuta1."AtDate"=pr."AsigStart" and valuta1."EID"=pr."AsigEID"
LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" valuta2 ON valuta2."AtDate"=pr."AsigStart" and valuta2."EID"='2'
where pr."PINDate" > '2020-08-01' and pr."IsRezil" = 'false'
```

When I run it with the conditions presented above(where statement) everything works fine.
However, when I try to run it with an earlier date eg. pr."PINDate > '2010-01-01' it appears an error 22P02: invalid input syntax for integer: "".
I was reading on other posts that there is a problem with the cast (). But I didn't manage to find a solution.
Looks like something doesn't match the datatype used.

Comment: Please don't post data as an image, supply it as formatted tabular `text` (like you did with your expected results) or as DDL and DML statements; we can't use the image to test, so it doesn't help us help you. Also, what have you tried to solve the problem yourself? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Does the sample table data and expected result really match? Table data has no code 15AXF for example.

Comment: Don't put that in the comments, @Alin-IustinianToderita . [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58215843/edit) your question and put your attempt in there (and replace the image with text).

Comment: You need to format it as code using the `{}` button in the editor, @Alin-IustinianToderita . I've done this for you.

Comment: On a different note, @Alin-IustinianToderita , I sugggest having a read of this: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `Pols` beings with `P` not "a", and `Riscs` with `R`, not "c". Using *good* aliasing is very important for readable and easily maintainable code, and I suggest having a read of the article for more reasons why.

Comment: Could you explain your results please? Where does the value `11` in `Index` come from, when no rows have a value of `11` for index in your sample data. You SQL also references 3 tables, but the sample data only has 1 table. Where are the other 2?

Comment: But if the sample data and expected results don't relate, how can I help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Index, Code, Count(*)
FROM [database_name]
GROUP BY Code, Index
ORDER BY Index;
```